# How to find the window MS Word in order to sub-class and override WndProc

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-word, nativewindow

I need to use custom event processing for ebedded Office applications in a WebBrowser ActiveX control. I have made great progress using the WebBrowser as a container for Word, Excel and PowerPoint and so far with some work I'm able to get almost all the behavior I require. However, the one thing I need to be able to do is to detect mouse clicks in a document and differentiate those that are on hyperlinks from those that are not.

I've been able to get close to a solution using a global hook but the process/logic I use for Word doesn't work for Excel.

In any case, after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766534/subclassing-ms-words-window-from-a-vsto-add-in) I decided overriding WndProc might be a better approach. Using the following code I put together a NativeWindow sub-class and an override for the WndProc. Unfortunately, it is never called so I assume I'm not using the correct window handle to instantiate it.

I use the class like this:

```
wordDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SetFocus()
hWndOffice = GetFocus()
officeWindow = New OfficeWindow(hWndOffice)
```

I'm using VB .NET but not VSTO...

Any ideas how to get the correct window handle?

```
Friend Class OfficeWindow
Inherits NativeWindow
Implements IDisposable

Public Sub New(handle As IntPtr)
    Me.AssignHandle(handle)
End Sub

<System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSetAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Msg)
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case &H200
            Console.WriteLine("WM_MOUSEMOVE")
    End Select
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

' Flag: Has Dispose already been called? 
Dim disposed As Boolean = False

' Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers. 
Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

' Protected implementation of Dispose pattern. 
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If disposed Then Return

    If disposing Then
        ' Free any other managed objects here. 
        ' 
        Me.DestroyHandle()
    End If

    ' Free any unmanaged objects here. 
    '
    disposed = True
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    Dispose(False)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You cannot subclass a window that's owned by a different process.  Code injection is required.  VSTO is the only reasonable approach to injecting VB.NET code.  Word exposes a window handle through the Window.Hwnd property.

Comment: This makes sense. I will try and see how far I get.